# Side effects to closing an HTML FORM child tag?

Tags: html, forms

If I do the following inside of an HTML FORM:

```
<input type="text"/>
```

vs

```
<input type="text">
```

are there any side effects to the first technique of closing the tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The `/` is ignored. It is just syntactic sugar for people addicted to XML or who have poor syntax highlighters.

(*Technically* in HTML 4 the `/` closes the tag so the `>` is a greater then sign as *data* but Emacs-W3 was the only browser I ever saw that implemented that and they removed support in the early 2000s because XHTML had Appendix C).